customized legend marker created with tikzset
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}


% Define TikZ styles for interpolation points and values
\newcommand{\interpolationPointStyle}{%
    \tikzset{interpolation point/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=black}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\interpolationPointStyle

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
clip=false,
]

% Define array of tick positions
\def\myxticks{3, 4, 5}
% Loop over tick positions and draw interpolation points
\foreach \tick in \myxticks {
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[interpolation point] at (axis cs:\tick,0) {};}
    \tmp
}
% Curve 1
\addplot[color=red, mark=none, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};
\addlegendentry{Curve 1}

% Interpolation points
\addlegendimage{interpolation point}
\addlegendentry{Interpolation Points}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

producing the output

Question:
I want to have the interpolation point symbol that I drawed on the x axis in the legend.
I thought this works by placing it in a legend image, but a straight line appears.
What must be corrected?

So this is my modification to your code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Define TikZ styles for interpolation points and values
\newcommand{\interpolationPointStyle}{%
    \tikzset{interpolation point/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=black}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\interpolationPointStyle

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    clip=false,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1}
]

% Define array of tick positions
\def\myxticks{3, 4, 5}
% Loop over tick positions and draw interpolation points
\foreach \tick in \myxticks {
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[interpolation point] at (axis cs:\tick,0) {};}
    \tmp
}
% Curve 1
\addplot[color=red, mark=none, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};
\addlegendentry{Curve 1}

% Manually create legend entry for interpolation points
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=black, scale=0.8}}
\addlegendentry{Interpolation Points}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


That should produce an output like this:

I took the liberty of placing the legend at the bottom. Sorry about that. I personally think that you are facing issues because \addlegendimage doesn't directly use the TikZ drawing commands, so it's not recognizing the TikZ style for your interpolation points.
That's just my theory though, I'm not 100% sure.

Hard-coding is not my preferred my solution, because if I change the tikzset command, I have to change it manually at several places. Hopefully there is a solution based on the macro I created

I found a solution to my problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}


% Define TikZ styles for interpolation points
\newcommand{\interpolationPointStyle}{%
    \tikzset{interpolation point/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=black}}
}

% Define custom legend styles for interpolation points 
\pgfplotsset{
    interpolation point legend/.style={
        legend image code/.code={
            \node[interpolation point] at (0.3cm,0cm) {};
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\interpolationPointStyle

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,
    xtick=\empty,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
clip=false,
]

% Define array of tick positions
\def\myxticks{3, 4, 5}
% Loop over tick positions and draw interpolation points
\foreach \tick in \myxticks {
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\node[interpolation point] at (axis cs:\tick,0) {};}
    \tmp
}
% Curve 1
\addplot[color=red, mark=none, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};
\addlegendentry{Curve 1}

\addlegendimage{interpolation point legend}
\addlegendentry{Interpolation Points}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Output:

